# Как указать путь к файлу, который находится в папке пользователя, а я не знаю имя пользователя

Tags: c++, windows, файлы, файловая-система, fstream

Всем привет, у меня проблема. Мне надо работать с файлами в appdata, а appdata находиться в папке пользователя, а имя пользователя соответсвенно у меня нет. Если что я работаю с библиотекой fstream, как получить имя пользователя и сделать так?:
fstream pr;
pr.open("C:\Users" + username "\AppData\LocalLow\Innersloth\Among Us"); //username это имя пользователя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте функцию `std::getenv("USERNAME")` или `std::getenv("USER")`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я долго исправлял ошибку то что типо эта функция не безопасна, в ошибке было сказано использовать другую функцию, таким же образом она не работала, и в офицальных доках ничего не было. Надо было зайти в Проект -> Свойства -> C/C++ -> Проверки SDL -> Нет(/sdl-)

Answer (score 1):

А кто вам гарантирует, что папка профиля расположена на диске `С:\users`? Кто вам гарантирует, что имя папки профиля совпадает с логином?

Нужно использовать переменную окружения `USERPROFILE`, а не хордкодить `C:\users\%USERNAME%`